# Delete row's with a lower number value

Tags: excel, vba

Having a bit of trouble with the below macro.  The idea is that it will look through the records on the 'Paste' sheet and compare against the number saved in 'B1' on the 'LastRun' sheet and remove the row if the number is lower.  When running the macro, it gets stuck on the 'End If' section.

```
Sub DeleteOld()
    Worksheets("Paste").Activate

        endrow = Sheets("Paste").Range("X2000").End(xlUp).Row
        OldData = Sheets("LastRun").Range("B1").Value
        For i = endrow To 2 Step -1
         NewData = Cells(i, 24).Value
             If NewData < OldData Then
             Cells(i, 24).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does "it gets stuck" exactly mean?

Comment: Sorry about that - it appears to become a problem at the 'End If' stage.

Comment: Well, but what exactly happens? Is it throwing an error? Is it just waiting forever? Or does something else happen?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteOld()

Dim endrow As Long, i As Long
Dim newdata As Double, olddata As Double


olddata = Sheets("LastRun").Range("B1").Value

    With Worksheets("Paste")

        endrow = .Range("X2000").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = endrow To 1 Step -1

         newdata = .Cells(i, 24).Value

             If newdata < olddata Then

             .Cells(i, 24).EntireRow.Delete

             End If

          Next i

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nikolaos, thanks for the code - it works well, however it requires me to run it twice to remove all the correct records.  I can't see any reason as to why it would not remove the rows on the first run?

Comment: please give an example...the only issue can see is if the value is in the first Row if this is the issue then change For i = endrow To 2 Step -1 with For i = endrow To 1 Step -1

Comment: When i run the macro for the first time it will delete 1 record - the second time i run it (without changing anything else in the sheet), it will delete the correct amount (in this case 212 records).  I'm not sure why it won't just delete the correct records on the initial run.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. However, in order to simplify, it's checking the value in the first column in the sheet where row deletion should take place.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

 Dim rngB2 As Range
 Set rngB2 = Sheets("lastRun").Cells(1, 2)

  With Sheets("paste")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    Dim curRng As Range
    Set curRng = .Cells(i, 1)
    If curRng.Value < rngB2.Value Then
    .Rows(curRng.Row).Delete
    'curRng.Interior.Color = rgbRed
    End If
  Next i

  End With

End Sub
```